# How to merge values of a row to two columns in sql

Tags: sql

Table 1

```
ID  Employee ID
1   200678
2   3000033
3   4454545
4   2323232
5   43345563
6   8473434
7   234234
8   766566
```

Table 2

```
ID  year    Manger id
1   2015    8
1   2014    7
2   2015    5
2   2014    6
3   2015    5
3   2014    4
4   2015    1
4   2014    2
```

Output

```
ID  Current year Manger ID  Prev Manager id
1   766566                  234234
2   43345563                8473434
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: explain your output please.

Comment: Only ID 1,2 is needed or all ID from table 2

Comment: Name tables, explain output. Also you wrote "Current year **Manger ID**" and "Prev **Manager id**" while values seem to be `Employee ID` from Table 1.

Answer (score 2):

In *SQL-Server* you can do something like this:

**SAMPLE DATA**

---

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
ID INT,
[Employee ID] INT
)
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES
(1,   200678   ),
(2,   3000033  ),
(3,   4454545  ),
(4,   2323232  ),
(5,   43345563 ),
(6,   8473434  ),
(7,   234234   ),
(8,   766566   )

CREATE TABLE #Table2
(
ID  INT,
years NVARCHAR(100),   
[Manger id] INT
)
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES
(1,   '2015',    8),
(1,   '2014',    7),
(2,   '2015',    5),
(2,   '2014',    6),
(3,   '2015',    5),
(3,   '2014',    4),
(4,   '2015',    1),
(4,   '2014',    2)
```

---

**QUERY**

```
SELECT t2.ID, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN years = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN [Employee ID] END) AS [Current year Manger ID],
       MIN(CASE WHEN years = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 THEN [Employee ID] END) AS [Prev Manager id]
FROM #Table1 t1
JOIN #Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.[Manger id]
GROUP BY t2.ID
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
ID  Current year Manger ID  Prev Manager id
1   766566                  234234
2   43345563                8473434
3   43345563                2323232
4   200678                  3000033
```

---

**DEMO**

You can test It at: <kbd>**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec80a/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Can't you replace '2015' (and '2014') with a "current year"-function, so the query will work next year too?

Comment: Updated an answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but i would require based on the table 1. Is it possible to bring?

Comment: @Chandramohan what do you mean based on 1 table? You provided 2 tables in your question.

Comment: I really sorry little confused. Year will having reference to other table. sorry i have not initially posted this.       select
o.PF,
case when o.ReviewYear = '7A925DD0' then  o.RepToPF end as currentyea,
case when o.ReviewYear = '047CA8B1' then o.RepToPF end as previusyear
from 
Employee e inner join OrgData o on e.Oid = o.PF
group by o.pf